# items in custom listview not recycling with new json data android

Tags: android, listview, adapter, recycle

I am using a custom `listview` which has 2 different layout for single item.

My json data :

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "response": [
        {
            "store_id": "1",
            "store_name": "Prashant Stores",
            "items": [
                {
                    "item_id": "1",
                    "item_name": "Kellogs Cornflakes",
                    "item_price": "75",
                    "item_size": "500 mg",
                    "item_quantity": "1",
                    "item_total": "75",
                    "delivery_boy_status_id": "3",
                    "delivery_boy_status": "Delivered",
                    "is_available": "1"
                },
                {
                    "item_id": "2",
                    "item_name": "Chocos",
                    "item_price": "75",
                    "item_size": "1 kg",
                    "item_quantity": "1",
                    "item_total": "75",
                    "delivery_boy_status_id": "3",
                    "delivery_boy_status": "Delivered",
                    "is_available": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "store_id": "5",
            "store_name": "Corner Stores",
            "items": [
                {
                    "item_id": "4",
                    "item_name": "Chocos",
                    "item_price": "400",
                    "item_size": "1 kg",
                    "item_quantity": "1",
                    "item_total": "400",
                    "delivery_boy_status_id": "1",
                    "delivery_boy_status": "To be Collected",
                    "is_available": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "message": ""
}
```

required output :

[image]
my activity

```
hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    jsonObj = userFunction.getCustomerWiseDetails(deliveryBoyID, token, orderID);

                    Log.e(TAG, jsonObj.toString());
                    status = jsonObj.getString("status");
                    message = jsonObj.getString("message");

                    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

                        jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("response");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            customerwiseDetailsListData = new ArrayList<>();
//                            customerwiseDetailsModel1.setStore_id(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("store_id"));
//                            customerwiseDetailsModel1.setStore_name(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("store_name"));
                            JSONObject jsonObjResponse = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONArray jsonArrayItem = jsonObjResponse.getJSONArray("items");
                            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayItem.length(); j++) {

                                customerwiseDetailsModel = new CustomerwiseDetailsModel();
                                customerwiseDetailsModel.setStore_id(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("store_id"));
                                customerwiseDetailsModel.setStore_name(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("store_name"));
                                customerwiseDetailsModel.setItem_id(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("item_id"));
                                customerwiseDetailsModel.setItem_name(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("item_name"));
                                customerwiseDetailsModel.setItem_price(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("item_price"));
                                customerwiseDetailsModel.setItem_size(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("item_size"));
                                customerwiseDetailsModel.setItem_quantity(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("item_quantity"));
                                customerwiseDetailsModel.setItem_total(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("item_total"));
                                customerwiseDetailsModel.setDelivery_boy_status_id(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("delivery_boy_status_id"));
                                customerwiseDetailsModel.setDelivery_boy_status(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("delivery_boy_status"));
                                customerwiseDetailsModel.setIs_available(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("is_available"));
                                if (j == (jsonArrayItem.length() - 1))
                                    customerwiseDetailsModel.visible = "0";
                                else
                                    customerwiseDetailsModel.visible = "1";

                                customerwiseDetailsListData.add(customerwiseDetailsModel);

                                hashMap.put(i, customerwiseDetailsListData);
                            }
                        }
```

my adapter

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        itemsData =  hasMap.get(position);

        Log.d(TAG," hasMap "+hasMap.toString());
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_neworders_customer_wise_details, null, false);
            viewHolder.txt_store_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.storename);


            viewHolder.container = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.neworders_customer_wise_details_container);


            for (int i=0;i<itemsData.size();i++){
                CustomerwiseDetailsModel test = itemsData.get(i);

                Log.d(TAG," test "+itemsData.get(i).getStore_name());

                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.neworders_customer_wise_details_linearlayout, null);

                viewHolder.txt_item_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_name);
                viewHolder.txt_item_size = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_weight);
                viewHolder.txt_item_quantity = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_recurring_total_price_qnty);
                viewHolder.txt_item_total = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_recurring_total_price);
                viewHolder.divider = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.divider);

                viewHolder.container.addView(view);

                viewHolder.txt_store_name.setText(test.getStore_name());
                viewHolder.txt_item_name.setText(test.getItem_name());
                viewHolder.txt_item_size.setText(test.getItem_size());
                viewHolder.txt_item_quantity.setText(test.getItem_price() + " x" + test.getItem_quantity());
                viewHolder.txt_item_total.setText(test.getItem_total());

            }
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

when is scroll my `listview`  the last item in the list doesn't gives me the updated value from the data.

I see the 2nd item value in the list repeated for the last.

my asynctask

```
class GetCustomerWiseDetails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        String status, message;
        JSONArray jsonArray;
        JSONObject jsonItems;
        String deliveryBoyID, token;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            error_flag = 0;
            listviewCustomerWiseDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            error_layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            img_no_internet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            img_no_results.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            img_server_error.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Getting customers ...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();


            deliveryBoyID = utilClass.getSharePerefernce(CustomerwiseDetailsActivity.this, UtilClass.KEY_DELIVETY_BY_ID, "0");
            token = utilClass.getSharePerefernce(CustomerwiseDetailsActivity.this, UtilClass.KEY_TOKEN, "0");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            if (NetworkCheck.isNetworkAvailable(CustomerwiseDetailsActivity.this)) {
                try {

                        hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        jsonObj = userFunction.getCustomerWiseDetails(deliveryBoyID, token, orderID);

                        Log.e(TAG, jsonObj.toString());
                        status = jsonObj.getString("status");
                        message = jsonObj.getString("message");

                        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

                            jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("response");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                customerwiseDetailsListData = new ArrayList<>();
    //                            customerwiseDetailsModel1.setStore_id(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("store_id"));
    //                            customerwiseDetailsModel1.setStore_name(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("store_name"));
                                JSONObject jsonObjResponse = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                JSONArray jsonArrayItem = jsonObjResponse.getJSONArray("items");
                                for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayItem.length(); j++) {

                                    customerwiseDetailsModel = new CustomerwiseDetailsModel();
                                    customerwiseDetailsModel.setStore_id(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("store_id"));
                                    customerwiseDetailsModel.setStore_name(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("store_name"));
                                    customerwiseDetailsModel.setItem_id(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("item_id"));
                                    customerwiseDetailsModel.setItem_name(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("item_name"));
                                    customerwiseDetailsModel.setItem_price(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("item_price"));
                                    customerwiseDetailsModel.setItem_size(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("item_size"));
                                    customerwiseDetailsModel.setItem_quantity(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("item_quantity"));
                                    customerwiseDetailsModel.setItem_total(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("item_total"));
                                    customerwiseDetailsModel.setDelivery_boy_status_id(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("delivery_boy_status_id"));
                                    customerwiseDetailsModel.setDelivery_boy_status(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("delivery_boy_status"));
                                    customerwiseDetailsModel.setIs_available(jsonArrayItem.getJSONObject(j).getString("is_available"));
                                    if (j == (jsonArrayItem.length() - 1))
                                        customerwiseDetailsModel.visible = "0";
                                    else
                                        customerwiseDetailsModel.visible = "1";

                                    customerwiseDetailsListData.add(customerwiseDetailsModel);

                                    hashMap.put(i, customerwiseDetailsListData);

                                }
                            }


                    } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("invalid parameters")) {
                        error_flag = 2;
                        Log.e(TAG, "invalid parameters");
                    } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("invalid user")) {
                        error_flag = 3;
                        Log.e(TAG, "No Data");
                    } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("error")) {
                        error_flag = 3;
                        Log.e(TAG, "No Data");
                    }
                    Log.e(TAG, "****** status " + status);
                    return String.valueOf(jsonObj);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    status = "Error";
                    error_flag = 2;
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                }
            } else {
                error_flag = 1;
                Log.e(TAG, "Network Error");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            super.onPostExecute(response);

            Log.e(TAG, "  **** error **** " + error_flag);

            if (error_flag == 1) {
                listviewCustomerWiseDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                error_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img_no_internet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (error_flag == 2) {
                listviewCustomerWiseDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                error_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img_server_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (error_flag == 3) {
                listviewCustomerWiseDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                error_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                img_no_results.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (error_flag == 0) {
                customerwiseDeatilsAdapter = new CustomerwiseDeatilsAdapter(CustomerwiseDetailsActivity.this, hashMap);
                listviewCustomerWiseDetails.setAdapter(customerwiseDeatilsAdapter);
                customerwiseDeatilsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if ((progressDialog != null) && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            progressDialog = null;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you should move `for (int i=0;i<itemsData.size();i++){...}` outside `if-else` block just before  `return convertView;`

Comment: if i do this .. the items count get increase in the layout while scrolling

Comment: @karthikkolanji move the for loop outside the if condition and write it below the else block and dont forget to write  viewHolder.container.removeAllViews()  before the for loop.

Comment: for (int i=0;i<itemsData.size();i++){
            viewHolder.container.removeAllViews(); ..... This gives me only one item inside each header , even though there is 2.

Comment: write this --> viewHolder.container.removeAllViews() outside for loop

Comment: no man ... it removed every item .. I can see only the header :(

Comment: are you writing all this outside the else block or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94385/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-karthik-kolanji).

Comment: yes  I am ... I solved this by else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            viewHolder.container.removeAllViews();
        } ... but while scrolling my listview lags..:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite your code as below

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    itemsData =  hasMap.get(position);

    Log.d(TAG," hasMap "+hasMap.toString());
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_neworders_customer_wise_details, null, false);
        viewHolder.txt_store_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.storename);


        viewHolder.container = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.neworders_customer_wise_details_container);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.container.removeAllViews();
    for (int i=0;i<itemsData.size();i++){
        CustomerwiseDetailsModel test = itemsData.get(i);
        viewHolder.txt_store_name.setText(test.getStore_name());
        Log.d(TAG," test "+itemsData.get(i).getStore_name());

         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.neworders_customer_wise_details_linearlayout, null);

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_name)).setText(test.getItem_name());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_weight)).setText(test.getItem_size());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_recurring_total_price_qnty)).setText(test.getItem_price() + " x" + test.getItem_quantity());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_recurring_total_price)).setText(test.getItem_total());
        viewHolder.divider = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.divider);

        viewHolder.container.addView(view);

    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Didn't worked ... go only 1 header with all items added in it, which belonged to other headers

Comment: the position of the code  viewHolder.container.removeAllViews();
        viewHolder.txt_store_name.setText(test.getStore_name()); is not appropriate .. give nullpointer ..

Comment: That should not be the case as I dont see any fault in the code

Comment: Sorry bro ...its still lagging :( .. Any way u help em a lot .. to get the output and I am successful :)

Comment: anyways if its still lagging then give me the relevent classes and data I will make it running smooth and better go with recyclerview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94391/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-karthik-kolanji).

Answer (score 0):

After the loop in your activity, write this line:

```
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: but I initialise myAdapter in onPostExecute().

Comment: my asynctask posted :)